# How to use custom dialog in DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

In my application I want use **custom dialog** into `DialogFragment` . I can use `AlertDialog` into `DialogFragment` but I want use **custom dialog** instead of `AlertDialog`.

**I write below codes into `DialogFragment` :**

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_comment, null);

    initVar();
    initView(rootView);
    initFunctionality();

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
            .setView(rootView)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    authorName = edtAuthorName.getText().toString().trim();
                    authorEmail = edtAuthorEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    authorComment = edtAuthorComment.getText().toString().trim();

                    AppPreference.getInstance(mActivity).setString(PrefKey.KEY_EMAIL, authorEmail);
                    AppPreference.getInstance(mActivity).setString(PrefKey.KEY_NAME, authorName);

                    if (commentId == AppConstant.THIS_IS_COMMENT) {
                        sendComment(authorName, authorEmail, authorComment);

                    } else {
                        sendReply(authorName, authorEmail, authorComment);
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (dialogInterface != null) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            })
            .create();
}
```

**I want use below code instead of above `AlertDialog` :**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mActivity);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_dialog_comment);
edtAuthorName = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_author_name);
edtAuthorEmail = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_author_email);
edtAuthorComment = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_author_comment);
dialogComment_okBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogComment_okBtn);
dialogComment_cancelBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogComment_cancelBtn);

edtAuthorName.setText(AppPreference.getInstance(mActivity).getString(PrefKey.KEY_NAME));

dialogComment_cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});

dialogComment_okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        authorName = edtAuthorName.getText().toString().trim();
        authorEmail = edtAuthorEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        authorComment = edtAuthorComment.getText().toString().trim();

        AppPreference.getInstance(mActivity).setString(PrefKey.KEY_EMAIL, "noEmail@gmail.com");
        AppPreference.getInstance(mActivity).setString(PrefKey.KEY_NAME, authorName);

        if (commentId == AppConstant.THIS_IS_COMMENT) {
            sendComment(authorName, "noEmail@gmail.com", authorComment);

        } else {
            sendReply(authorName, "noEmail@gmail.com", authorComment);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

How can I it? Please don't give me negative points and please help me

Comment: What problems are you having using the custom `Dialog`? You can return any kind of `Dialog` from `onCreateDialog()`. It doesn't have to be an `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your class with **DialogFragment** and rest will be like fragments like

```
public class YOurDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
 @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
      //If don't want toolbar
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
 }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.customLayout, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
```